# How to check that during unit testing with ng-test, fdescribe() and fit() are never called?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, deployment, describe

Simple scenario, angular, unit testing and continuous deployment.
What can happen is that a developer finishes the unit test related to a component. During development time the developer uses the functions `fdescribe()` or `fit()` just to run those specific tests.

In a moment of distraction the developer commits and pushes and deploy is done on production, but `fdescribe()` or `fit()` was forgotten in the code.

Tests are not failing, but this brings a bad scenario in, basically all the regular tests are not running, but the traffic-light says GO and all deploy is done.

Is it possible to check that in the all unit tests any `fdescribe()` or `fit()` are called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a [`pre-commit` Git Hook](https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that will check that `fdescribe()` and `fit()` (and any code you don't want to be committed) aren't present in your test files.

[Here's](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-commit.sample) an example code you can find on [githooks](https://githooks.com/).

In your case, I think [this pre-commit code](https://github.com/netresearch/git-client-hooks/blob/master/hooks/pre-commit-check-coding-style) could be very useful given that it will check all files in staging area that are added, modified or renamed but not deletions.

Comment: I will check it asap and let you know! thanks for now